# Application of ramp frequency

Tags: frequency

What is the application for the ramp frequency function? For example, I know that ramping from 1kHz to 100kHz in 1kHz increments is one way of determining the stability of a device under test. But other than that, are there any other applications for a frequency ramp?

Comment: There is a device called a sweep frequency response analyzer which is used to "fingerprint" expensive transformers. Using a frequency ramp, you can analyze the magnetizing current into the transformer. If the transformer gets severely overloaded by an fault, but still appears to be intact, they will run the sweep analysis again to see if the core suffered damage from the original baseline.

Comment: Also, any precision measurement of an inductance or a capacitance will use some kind of frequency ramp, to check for changing values under various conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think that applying such a frequency ramp to any device can reveal its stability properties. If a circuit is unstable, it will oscillate or remain in a kind of saturation - independent on the excitation at its input..

However, a very important application of such a frequency sweep is to measure the frequency response of filters - for example, in conjunction with signal analyzers.
Thus, you are able t display the transfer curve (amplitude and/or phase vs. frequency) on the screen.

Comment: u means that by ramping the frequency , we can determine the cutoff frequency of the filter?let say we supply 10 to 40kHz frequency to the filter, from the oscilloscope, if the amplitude have drop 3db on 30kHz, then the cutoff frequency equal to the 30kHz?

Comment: Yes - of course. And not only the cut-off frequency: You can see/control the attenuation properties of the filter (how many dB at selected frequencies, which are the reason for the need of such a filter).

Comment: As currently I am confusing, as somebody told me stability need determine by plotting bode plot, and then need to do fast fourier transform from the waveform of oscillscope, but I am wondering how to represent the waveform on the oscilloscope in frequency domain?beside using spectrum analyzer

Comment: The classical method for creating a BODE plot is to use such a frequency sweep in conjunction with a network analyzer which is able to plot magnitude and phase as a function of frequency. Beside this practical method, it is very common to use a simulation program to perform stability analyses (BODE plot).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen audio ramp generators used when setting up sound systems in big concerts/gigs. This will stimulate the big power amps and speaker stacks and a microphone will be used to analyse the spectrum. Deficiencies in the spectrum are corrected with a graphic equalizer. They also use pink noise but more recently I've seen short pulsing ramps being used.